# Como Centralizar Menu em css?

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber como posso centralizar o menu abaixo:

```css
.dropdownmenu ul, .dropdownmenu li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.dropdownmenu ul {
 background: gray;
 list-style: none;
 width: 100%;
}
.dropdownmenu li {
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
}
.dropdownmenu a {
 background: #30A6E6;
 color: #ffffff;
 display: block;
 font: bold 12px/20px sans-serif;
 padding: 10px 25px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
 -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
 -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
 -o-transition: all .25s ease;
 transition: all .25s ease;
}
.dropdownmenu li:hover a {
 background: #000000;
}
#submenu {
 left: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 35px;
 visibility: hidden;
 z-index: 1;
}
li:hover ul#submenu {
 opacity: 1;
 top: 40px; /* adjust this as per top nav padding top & bottom comes */
 visibility: visible;
}
#submenu li {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
}
#submenu a:hover {
 background: #000000;
}
#submenu a {
 background-color:#30A6E6;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="dropdownmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a>
      <ul id="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">História</a></li>
        <li><a href="sejasocio.html">Seja Sócio</a></li>
        <li><a href="nucleos.html">Núcleos</a></li>
         <li><a href="aliados.html">Aliados</a></li>
          <li><a href="gestao.html">Diretoria</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="noticias.html">Notícias</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Interativo</a>
      <ul id="submenu">
        <li><a href="musicas.html">Músicas</a></li>
        <li><a href="fotos.html">Fotos</a></li>
        <li><a href="videos.html">Vídeos</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="loja.html">Loja</a></li>
    <li><a href="contato.html">Contato</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
  
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer de algumas maneiras, seguem duas:

1.

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
nav.dropdownmenu {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

2.

```
nav.dropdownmenu {
    width: 1200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**EDIT**

Caso você queira reverter a ordem do menu para a forma lógica, faça a troca do float de `right` para `left` na seguinte classe.

```
.dropdownmenu li {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Está igual ao exemplo dele. Nada mudou de ordem.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Sim, o seu exemplo está na forma lógica, mas no exemplo dele está invertido. Ele não pediu para reverter.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Botei um Edit caso ele queira reverter.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Está ok, né? Essa seria a forma sensata de se fazer, mas o `float: right;` tem esse costume de inverter tudo. O problema é que eu não posso assumir que ele não fez de propósito sem ele ter dito nada à respeito.

Comment: Opa, Consegui centralizar ele, mas não remover os espaços entre as bordas da página
 
Ele tava com uma margin distante do top, usei um margin-top -3px; resolveu
agora faltou os dois lados rsrs
acho que podia deixar o inicio mais pro lado direito do site e deixar as borbas mais largas entre o inicio e o contato.

Comment: @LucianoBarbosa Vê se um: `body { margin: 0; }`, não resolve seu problema.

Comment: Resolveu sim, obrigadão mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.dropdownmenu {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdownmenu ul ul {
    display: none;
}

.dropdownmenu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.dropdownmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    background: gray;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; 
}

.dropdownmenu ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.dropdownmenu ul li a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: #30A6E6;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: bold 12px/20px sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}  

.dropdownmenu ul li ul li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #000000;
}    

.dropdownmenu ul li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #000000;
}  

.dropdownmenu ul ul {
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.dropdownmenu ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    position: relative;
}

.dropdownmenu ul li ul li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #30A6E6;
}

.dropdownmenu ul li ul li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdownmenu ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

> Para colocar o menu na ordem inversa faça a troca do float de `left`  para `right`  na seguinte classe.

```
.dropdownmenu ul li {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Coloca alguma explicação na resposta, por favor.